# Align Button to the right in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, autolayout

I want to have a button in my custom cell which is right aligned. Doing it with auto layout and setting a horizontal space from the right and centering it vertical does not show the Button in my cell because it is too far at the right.

[image: MyCell]

In the picture you can see my cell. But it is not shown like this in the actual app.

Edit: I tried your answer but this does not seem to work. My TableView looks kind of strange in the Emulator:

[image]

Is it possible that there is a problem in my controller?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("eventCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as EventTableViewCell

    let event = items[indexPath.row]

    cell.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sry I am dumb. 
Everything was fine with my Cell layout. I was so focused on the cell that I forgot to add constraints to the TableView. Adding these constraints fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following for that Button:

1. Set `Width and Height constraints`
2. set Vertical center constraints to the cell view
3. Set horizontal/trailing(may be 10px) space to the right side of the cell view